# How to create an AdCreative with the Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to create ads through the Facebook Marketing API with a test app in development mode.

When I first tried, I got an error message which told me that I had to switch my app to public mode to do that, but when I did I got another error message which told me that I miss the ads management permission. So I tried to regenerate an access token, but it seems I can't have the permission I need when my app is in public mode.

I first tried to generate it via the app's dashboard, in Marketing API > Tools. But when the app is in public mode, the "Get token" button is disabled. Then I tried to do it with the Graph API Explorer, but the ads_management permission doesn't appear in the list. So it seems there is no way to have the kind of access token I need when my app is in public mode.

I already developed the features to manage campaigns and ad sets with no problem, with my app in development mode.

Here's the error I get when I try to create an ad in development mode :

`Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.`

And when I switch my app to public mode :

`(#200) Requires ads_management permission to manage the object`

I read a lot of documentation but I don't find it very clear about what I'm supposed to do at this step. Do I really need to submit my app for review to be able to require the right permissions in public mode ? Is this going to take long, like a few days or weeks ? That seems weird to me that I need to go through that in the development stage of my app, I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance and sorry if this sounds like a naive question.